# Streaming directly from IBM COS (Cloud Object Storage)?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I am working on video streaming with nodejs server. I'm using IBM Cloud Object Storage (COS) bucket as video storage. 
Nodejs app is running in a Cloud Foundry (PAAS) instance. To stream a specific video file in response to a client's request, the file needs to be downloaded from COS bucket to Cloud Foundry instance (temp folder in nodejs server, whit disk space limits). 
It's time consuming process and client has to wait too much time before the video reproduction. I am looking for a way to remove the downloading time interval.

Is there a way to directly stream from IBM COS bucket?

Thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to use a CDN for that use case. Here's a tutorial on using the IBM CDN for streaming from COS. https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/static-files-cdn.html#accelerate-delivery-of-static-files-using-a-cdn

Comment: Thanks so much! That was what I looking for, and didn't know IBM Cloud was providing this service!

Comment: Just added it as an answer since this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

IBM has a [Content Delivery Network](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/cdn) that lets you stream media from Cloud Object Storage (COS). There is a tutorial in the documentation that goes through the process of steaming videos and pictures from COS. Here:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-static-files-cdn#accelerate-delivery-of-static-files-using-a-cdn